# WSL-Ubuntu Minecraft Java server restart, opens start.sh file incorrectly

Tags: bash, scripts, java, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run a PaperMC server and the restart function requires a start.sh file. I have created the file and it only works when I open it from the Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu terminal, but not when I open it from my file explorer or use the restart function. When the server starts up, it is running Java and when I use the restart function, it outputs "Attempting to restart with ./start.sh" I use that command in the normal shell, but it doesn't seem like it works when Java running in the normal shell tries to use it. Is it because I use the Windows java in the Ubuntu command shell? Can someone help me find a solution for this?

Comment: If it works from WSL and you’re asking how to get it to work from Windows then your question is off-topic here and should rather be asked on [su].

Comment: But within WSL, when I restart the server, it seems to be using the Windows protocol to open the script and I don't want that. If there's a way I can set Windows to open the file using WSL, then that would be great.